# Banner not closing and staying closed with link

Tags: jquery, html, mootools

Hey guys I have a banner I developed with mootools library. The banner only appears on smartphones but you can see it via Chrome Dev tools using the toggle device mode. Here is the link [Banner](http://mobileadoptionservices.com/freedombank/default-test.html)

My issue is that the banner has a "Do not show this again" link and it is not working.

this is part of the code I am using. It is using a cookie. Can someone let me know why its not firing off. I've looked and looked and just can't figure it out.

```
    /* Do not show window again */
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    if ($('#appnotice')) {

        var appnoticecloseElems = $$('.appnoticeclose'),
            appnoticecloseperm = $$('.appnoticecloseperm'),
            appnotice = $('#appnotice'),
            appnoticeHeight = appnotice.height(),
            appnoticePaddingTop = Math.abs(appnoticeHeight.toInt() - 5000),
            bypassappnotice = Cookie.read('bypassappnotice');

        appnotice.css('padding-top', appnoticePaddingTop);

        function appnoticeOpen() {
            console.log('appnoticeOpen');
            appnotice.css('display','block');
        }

        function appnoticeClose() {
            console.log('appnoticeClose');
            appnotice.css('display','none');
        }

        appnoticecloseElems.each(function(el, index) {
            $(el).click(function(){
                console.log('appnoticeclose');
                var bypassappnotice = Cookie.write('bypassappnotice', 'true');
                appnoticeClose();
            });
        });

        appnoticecloseperm.each(function(el, index) {
            el.click(function(){
                console.log('appnoticecloseperm');
                var bypassappnotice = Cookie.write('bypassappnotice', 'true', {
                    duration: 120
                });
                appnoticeClose();
            });
        });
    }

    if (bypassappnotice != 'true') {

        /* Detect Smartphone */
        var mobile = (/android/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
        if (mobile) {

            var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            if ((userAgent.search("android") > -1) && (userAgent.search("mobile") > -1))

                var element = document.getElementById("apppage").style.display = "none";
            var element = document.getElementById("googlePlayBadge")
                .innerHTML = "<a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fiserv.touchbankingasp&hl=en' target='_blank'><img src='https://developer.android.com/images/brand/en_generic_rgb_wo_60.png'></a>";

        }

        var mobile = (/iphone/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
        if (mobile) {
            var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            if ((userAgent.search("iphone") > -1) && (userAgent.search("mobile") > -1))

                var element = document.getElementById("apppage").style.display = "none";
            var element = document.getElementById("appStoreBadge")
                .innerHTML = "<a href='https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/touchbanking/id386678211?mt=8' target='_blank'><img src='http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_appstore-lrg.png'></a>";

        }
    }
});

/* Dismiss window ones */
function hideshow(which) {
    if (!document.getElementById)
        return
    if (which.style.display == "block")
        which.style.display = "none"
    else
        which.style.display = "block"
}
};
```

Comment: If you can make a jaFiddle would be great. Easyer to check and help.

Comment: Sergio I am not able to use jsFiddle because I am using document.write and jsFiddle does not allow it. I went and added here [link](https://jsbin.com/babavo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Can you explain more on what is not working? What behaviour you expect and do not get?

Comment: you can use `document.write` - replace with `var w = 'write'; ... document[w](...)` - but your don't show this again needs to set the cookie, where do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, get rid of one of the two libraries (jQuery / mootools). If that is not possible, at least use [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), in mootools avoid the $ sign or use or use the [The Dollar Safe Mode](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode).
Besides the unnecessarily gib footprint it really makes it hard to understand what happens here. 
e.g. el.click
 - in vanilla js triggers a click on that element, if el is a simple dom
   element
   - same with mootools, because mootools elements are still elements (which i appreciate btw)
   - in jquery it might be $(el) the its somthing like el.addEventListener('click', ..), the latter in mootools would be el.addEvent()

so what $$('.appnoticeclose') returns - mootools elements or jquery objects, makes a big difference. There also might be a race condition in which library is loaded last.

Comment: P.S. 
to get an element by id in jQuery: $('#my_id')
in mootools: $('my_id')
so your if ($('#appnotice')) {...} might never be true, if the dollar function is from mootools